# ¿Como leer solamente un registro de un DataGridView que tiene informacion de la BD? C#

Tags: c#, datatable

Mi problema es que quisiera leer el registro completo de una tabla de mi base de datos, bueno hasta el momento me trae la informacion y la plasma en el formulario que deberia, porque lo que quiero hacer es una actualizacion, solo que me lee todos los registros y el unico que me plasma es el ultimo registro de dicha tabla.

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            txtArticulo.Text = reader.GetString("Articulo");
            txtArticulo.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            txaDescripcion.Text = reader.GetString("Descripcion");
            txaDescripcion.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            txtCosto.Text = reader.GetString("Costo");
            txtCosto.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            spImportancia.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.GetString("Importancia"));

            if (reader.GetString("Obligatorio") == "no")
            {
                rbNo.Checked = true;

            }
            else if (reader.GetString("Obligatorio") == "si")
            {

                rbSi.Checked = true;

            }

        }
```

Esto me lee todos los registros, lo que yo quiero hacer es que solo me lea el registro que se selecciona en la tabla y me lo plasme en mi formulario.

Como se puede apreciar, seleccione el segundo registro, pero me plasma siempre el ultimo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el evento de tu Datagrid

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Y en tu consulta:

```
  string consulta_p = "SELECT * FROM tutabla WHERE id='" + id + "'";
  MySqlCommand Orden = new MySqlCommand(consulta_p,conexion);
  MySqlDataReader Lector = Orden.ExecuteReader();
   if (Lector.Read())
   {
    //El dato existe
    TextBox.Text1=lector["campo"].ToString());
   }else{
MessageBox.Show("NO EXISTE", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

  }
```